# Can I define an Interface that IDictionary implements in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

Say I have a function that needs to operate on a instance of `UsefulType`, but must take an argument of type `string`. To do so, within the function I might look up some `string -> OtherType` mapping. I could make an interface that looks like

```
public interface IMapper {
    public UsefulType this[string key];
    public bool ContainsKey(string key);
}
```

and give my method the signature

```
public Task DoSomething(string thing, IMapper lookup)
```

It is clear to me that an `IDictionary<string, UsefulType>` logically implements `IMapper`, but of course the canonical definition doesn't include `IMapper` in its inheritance tree. Does C# provide any functionality such that a user could pass a `Dictionary` directly into this function without having to worry about implementing their own `IMapper`?

(In reality the signature for `DoSomething` would just contain a string - that's the constraint - and the `IMapper` would be owned by `DoSomething`'s type. But I would still need the user to provide an `IMapper` for type instantiation, for example)

Comment: Why not just use a `IDictionary<string, UsefulType>` for `DoSomething` then? Or `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, UsefulType>`.

Comment: Purely because it seems like overkill if someone's not taking the `Dictionary` route to make them implement all  the other methods on `IDictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot retroactively make existing types implement/inherit other types, unless you are able to change their source code and recompile them.

Consider accepting an [`IReadOnlyDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=net-5.0) instead. It isn't that different from your `IMapper`. It shouldn't be *a lot* more to implement. `Count` should be trivial if your mapping is finite. `Keys` and `Values` all return `IEnumerable`s, so that gives you the ability to write iterators with `yield return` if it's inconvenient to return a collection. You can also write iterators in `GetEnumerator` (no need to implement your own `IEnumerator`), so IMO, it's not that much more work for finite mappings. You might not need these extra properties right now, but who knows, you might need them later!

If your mapping has infinitely many elements, then `Count` doesn't quite make sense. In that case, you can write a dictionary implementation of `IMapper`:

```
public class DictionaryMapper : IMapper
{
    private IReadOnlyDictionary<string, UsefulType> dict;
    public DictionaryMapper(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, UsefulType> dict)
    {
        this.dict = dict;
    }

    public UsefulType this[string key] => dict[key];

    public bool ContainsKey(string key) => dict.ContainsKey(key);
}
```

Now given a dictionary `d`, you can just do `new DictionaryMapper(d)` to get a `IMapper` implementation from that.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I expected. I thought I should check bc I've been writing a lot of Go recently, where method implementations alone define whether a struct implements an interface.